# How to get from a object list only one by object value

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-core

I have a complete list of objects "Person".

I need a short list that includes only the first person from each team, so some sort of grouping and the first item in each case

**How can I transfer the complete list into the short list with the first item per group and teamNumber?**

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person(){TeamNumber = 1, Name = "Peter"},
    new Person(){TeamNumber = 1, Name = "Klaus"},
    new Person(){TeamNumber = 1, Name = "Maria"},
    new Person(){TeamNumber = 1, Name = "Gerda"},
    new Person(){TeamNumber = 2, Name = "Ralf"},
    new Person(){TeamNumber = 2, Name = "Oskar"},
    new Person(){TeamNumber = 2, Name = "Anna"},
    new Person(){TeamNumber = 3, Name = "Hannah"},
    new Person(){TeamNumber = 3, Name = "Susi"},
    new Person(){TeamNumber = 4, Name = "Ida"}
};
```

I like to get a short list like:
(allways the first person per teamNumber)

- TeamNumber = 1, Name = "Peter"
- TeamNumber = 2, Name = "Ralf"
- TeamNumber = 3, Name = "Hannah"
- TeamNumber = 4, Name = "Ida"

class Person:

```
public class Person
{
    public int TeamNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you just `GroupBy` `TeamNumber` and then select `FirstOrDefault()` on `Name` ?

Comment: `var newList = list.GroupBy(e => e.TeamNumber).Select(e => new { TeamNumber = e.Key, Name = e.First().Name });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var result= list.GroupBy(t => t.TeamNumber).Select(p => p.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this:

First you `GroupBy` TeamNumber in order to (group them, so you only get one. Then you take the First record (`Person`) and selects that for that TeamNumber. Then you do it for the whole list, and returns it as a new List.

```
var shortList =  list.GroupBy(t => t.TeamNumber).Select(e => e.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

And then i would recommend you to read up on [linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/)